# by index switch to frame always fail,but I do not know why

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, iframe

a page has many iframes,and I want to switch to the second one,but when I switch to,the result is none,I do not know why.the code is:

```html
for i in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe'):
    print(i)
print('------------------------------------------------')
sencondfram=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[1]
print(sencondfram)
print('----------------------------------------')
frame=driver.switch_to.frame(sencondfram)
print(frame)
```

and the result is :

```html
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="85dc5a9cb0b168925371f68ddd4c953a", element="4d642df3-2996-4c79-b395-475c0dca3c33")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="85dc5a9cb0b168925371f68ddd4c953a", element="b31d4b05-7ab7-4a54-aa22-fce2c514778d")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="85dc5a9cb0b168925371f68ddd4c953a", element="08311bcd-3db1-427a-83fd-5f5d8230efab")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="85dc5a9cb0b168925371f68ddd4c953a", element="892a13d5-1eb7-41ae-8e74-63cfa1c3d912")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="85dc5a9cb0b168925371f68ddd4c953a", element="a87fdbb6-1d56-41c2-8e79-6cfe6fb1e7a6")>
------------------------------------------------
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="85dc5a9cb0b168925371f68ddd4c953a", element="b31d4b05-7ab7-4a54-aa22-fce2c514778d")>
----------------------------------------
None
```

However, the web page has five iframes, so why does Selenium fail nevertheless? How can I fix this?

Comment: Upload the HTML example too in order for us to see the platform you are testing.

Comment: can u provide url?